# Sorting a randomly generated array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, random

Hello I am working on a randomly generated list of numbers and need to sort them. Currently I have the numbers being generated into an array and output them. I need to be able to sort the numbers in ascending order. My problem is how to recall the random generated array to be sorted. So I can mark how much time it takes to sort the list.

```
import java.util.*;
public class project2 {
    public static int[] mklist(int len, int max, int min){
        Random r = new Random();
        int spread = max - min;
        int[] numbers = new int[len];
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) 
            numbers[i] = (r.nextInt() % (spread/2) + (spread/2)) + min;
        return numbers;
    }
    static void printarray(int[] A) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < A.length) {
            System.out.print(A[i] + " ");
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int[] tl;

        long StartTime = System.nanoTime();
        tl = mklist(10, 10000, 100);
        long EndTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Time to create list: " + (EndTime - StartTime)/1000000.0 + " milliseconds");
        printarray(tl);
    }
}
```

here is a sorter that works:

```
public static int[] ascending(int[] a){

    int temp;

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < a.length - 1; j++){
            if(a[j] > a[j+1]){
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j+1];
                a[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    return(a);
}
```

Comment: `ascending(tl);` ? Then do `printarray(tl);` again.  You already did the timer code, so just put that around these two method calls

Comment: You wrote all that code and you don't know how to call your method?  Something smells fishy...

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your current main method.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    int[] tl;

    long StartTime = System.nanoTime();
    tl = mklist(10, 10000, 100);
    long EndTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Time to create list: " + (EndTime - StartTime)/1000000.0 + " milliseconds");
    printarray(tl);
    StartTime = System.nanoTime();
    Arrays.sort(tl);
    EndTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Time to sort list: " + (EndTime - StartTime)/1000000.0 + " milliseconds");
    printarray(tl);
}
```